# AngularJS : $timeout is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I am trying to add a delay of 2000ms by using the timeout method but it is not working if I try to call it in the function(searchfunc) inside the cotroller. It gives Error: $timeout is not a function .
Controller code :

```
var angularjsapp = angular.module('graphApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap','ui.grid']);

angularjsapp.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.searchfunc = function(search_name,$timeout) {
        WebSocketTest(search_name,keyword_type);
        //$scope.loading = false;
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.loading = false;
        }, 2000);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `$timeout` as a parameter to your function

```
$scope.searchfunc = function(search_name,*$timeout*
```

which will make it undefined when you call the function because you don't pass it along. Removing it will fix the issue.

```
scope.searchfunc = function(search_name)
```

You can read about how this works (closures) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 1):

You override `$timeout` in the inner function.
Just omit it:

```
$scope.searchfunc = function(search_name) {
```

May be you mean second parameter to be `keyword_type`?
Because now it's looks like `undefined`.

```
$scope.searchfunc = function(search_name, keyword_type) {
```